# React native throws 'Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I get this error with `react-native run-android`
Here's the full log

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 's7sportsApp'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          :s7sportsApp:unspecified
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
>   >     Permission denied: connect
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Additionally...this error doesn't occur in my work computer.Why is that?

this is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```